# Emacs warning: "no version information available (required by emacs)"

Tags: emacs, linker, centos, shared-libraries

When I open emacs I am getting this warning

```
external/slc6_amd64_gcc630/lib/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by emacs)
```

I recently changed my system from sl6 to centos7. So, it is a result of this. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but I think you could get away with a symlink from your libtiff to the location expected by your emacs binary (assuming you don't just want to recompile / get an emacs binary for your distro).

Make a link to your libtiff wherever it may be,

```
find /usr/lib -name libtiff.so.5 2>/dev/null
```

or `locate libtiff.so.5`

from that expected by the emacs binary,

```
ldd /usr/bin/emacs | awk '/libtiff/ { print $3 }'
```

replacing the `/usr/lib/`, `/usr/bin/emacs` with your actual locations.

Comment: It worked for me. I basically had to append /usr/lib64/ to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and emacs was then able to find the correct library.